# Vue: How to manipulate and use mappedState data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component that uses `mapState` to pull in 2 different states from the user store.  In the user store, it makes a GQL call and gets a list of `potentialNames`.  While it is awaiting that query, `fetchingData` is `true` and afterwards, it is set to `false`.

```
<template>
     <div v-if="firstTenNames>

     </div>

</template>

export default ({

     data: {
       return() {
          firstTenNames: [],
       }
     },
     computed: {
         ...mapState('user', ['potentialNames', 'fetchingData']),
     }
});
```

I want to be able to know as soon as the data is fetched and `potentialNames` has a value so that I can `splice` off the first 10 names and set it to `firstTenNames`.  Is there a non-expensive way of doing this?  I was thinking of watching the property but is that the only way? Also, can you even `watch` it if it's a store property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to turn `firstTenNames` into a computed property

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['potentialNames', 'fetchingData']),

    // whenever `potentialNames` changes
    // this property is automatically recomputed
    firstTenNames() {
      // could be `null`, depending on your code
      if (this.potentialNames) {
        return this.poentialNames.slice(0, 10)
      }
      return []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`firtTenNames` is computed only based on another state (`potentialNames`). In that kind of situation, it's much easier to use a computed property that will make sure things are automatically in sync.

Yes, you can achieve the same by storing `firstTenNames` in `data` and adding a watcher for `potentialNames`. This is just more work and is error-prone especially if your state depends on multiple other values (e.g., you could easily forget to add some watchers).

There are some cases where using a watcher is actually needed (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). However, in most cases, computed properties are more appropriate.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, cheers!